# Is there a way to reduce the width of the left panel of Vuepress?

Tags: vuepress

I think that the left-pane in Vuepress is too wide. Wondering if there are any settings that would reduce the width of the left-hand panel?

Answer (score 2):

Add a file `override.styl` to the `.vuepress` folder, and add the following line to set side panel width (default is 20rem)

```
$sidebarWidth = 10rem
```

There's a bunch of other stuff that can go in here as well. To explore the options, use the command

```
vuepress eject ejected
```

then navigate to `/ejected/.vuepress/theme/styles/` and take a look at what style tags are used in the base project.

Be sure to remove the ejected files from the project if you want to update VuePress in the future.

Comment: How can we determine ALL the .styl variables that are editable? When I open the `/ejected/.vuepress/theme/` files, I see them ($varName) interspersed with the CSS. Not every control has a .styl variable though. A good example are the table controls in `/styles/theme.styl`. 

table
  border-collapse collapse
  margin 1rem 0
  display: block
  overflow-x: auto

tr
  border-top 1px solid #dfe2e5
  &:nth-child(2n)
    background-color #f6f8fa

th, td
  border 1px solid #dfe2e5
  padding .6em 1em

Comment: Things are a little bit weird - there is different style overrides for Vupress ver 0.x and ver 1.x - the above pertains to ver 0.x.

Comment: To answer your example of table styling, I added a table in the markdown and  `table { background-color blue; }` to `override.styl`, and blue background is the result. I think the trick is to inspect the page for the correct element & class selectors you want to target, then try them out in override.styl.

Comment: Thanks. Just so I'm clear: Add an element in a .md file, render it in VuePress, right click, inspect element.... but, was "table {... " the css selector or is it a .styl variable that you somehow knew to convert?

Comment: Yes, I added an table to the MD file [markdownguide](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables) which gets generated to a table element at runtime. `table {...` is a plain old css element selector. Not sure how far that will work with other parts of the compiled markdown. The problem would be specificity e.g for divs. I would tend towards [using a Vue component](https://v0.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-components) instead of markdown rather than spend time on coercing styles for the markdown.

Comment: Aha. Really I'm looking for a way to "show all possible style selectors" in a .styl format that I can manipulate in override.styl. Why is this so challenging?

Comment: I gathered that.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone comes across this question using Vuepress >= 1. In the new version of Vuepress, override.styl is deprecated and this is now done by creating a folder called `styles/` in `.vuepress/` and creating a file called `palette.styl`. You can then use the command from Richard's answer.